# scala coursera assignment method failing test

Tags: scala

I am doing scala course on coursera. I am going through week 6 assignment. I have created a function which finds the occurence of a char in a word. The test method is failing with respect to the expected result sequence.

Here is the problem description:

```
/** A word is simply a `String`. */
type Word = String
/** Converts the word into its character occurrence list.
*
*  Note: the uppercase and lowercase version of the character are treated as the
*  same character, and are represented as a lowercase character in the occurrence list.
*
*  Note: you must use `groupBy` to implement this method!
*/

def wordOccurrences(w: Word): Occurrences = {

   def breakWord(s: List[Char], xs: List[(Char, Int)]): List[(Char, Int)] = s match {
   case Nil => xs
   case char :: rest =>     breakWord(s.tail, matchTuple(xs, char))
   }

   breakWord(w.toList, List[(Char, Int)]())
}

 def matchTuple(tupleList: List[(Char, Int)], char: Char): List[(Char, Int)] = tupleList match {
 case Nil => tupleList:+ (char.toLower, 1)
 case pair :: restOfList => {
   if(pair._1.toLower == char.toLower)
      restOfList :+(pair._1, pair._2+1)
   else
      tupleList:+ (char.toLower, 1)
  }
}
```

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong. I do not need a direct answer, just a logical hint as to what is wrong with my sequence. Here is the test and its result:

```
 assert(wordOccurrences("Robert") === List(('b', 1), ('e', 1), ('o', 1), ('r', 2), ('t', 1)))
```

Here is the output:

```
[info] - wordOccurrences: Robert *** FAILED ***
[info]   List((o,1), (b,1), (e,1), (r,2), (t,1)) did not equal List((b,1), (e,1), (o,1), (r,2), (t,1)) (AnagramsSuite.scala:20)
```

**Update**:
Refactored my function:

```
def wordOccurrences(w: Word): Occurrences = {

    def breakWord(s: List[Char], xs: List[(Char, Int)]): List[(Char, Int)] = s match {
      case Nil => xs
      case char :: rest =>     breakWord(s.tail, xs:+ (char, 1))
    }

    breakWord(w.toList, List[(Char, Int)]()).groupBy( pair => pair._1.toLower)
      .map(entry => (entry._1.toLower, (entry._1.toLower, entry._2.size)) )
      .values.toList.sorted
  }
```

It looks too bad, but I will work on to improve this method further.

Comment: Where's the `groupBy` that you are instructed (commanded!) to use?

Comment: Did not get how to call it. Will study how to use it here.

Comment: I recommend it. This can be solved with just 1 line of code. `groupBy` is a small, but important, part of it.

Comment: I have created a work around for now with sortBy. But I will definitely solve this groupBy logic before I submit my code.

Answer (score 2):

The result you get is fine, it's just in different order, <s>but the task doesn't seem to say anything about a specific order being required</s>. So you need to sort it afterwards (before or after modifying the solution to use `groupBy`). You can just call `sorted` method to do that (or lookup `sortBy`/`sortWith`).

Comment: The OP didn't include this in the question, but the instructions/description for `Occurrences` explicitly state: "... is sorted alphabetically ..."

Comment: @jwvh Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @jwvh: Thanks. Probably this is the important aspect I missed from problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

you can count occurences from this method -

```
def times(chars: List[Char]): List[(Char, Int)] = {
  def rec(charList: List[Char], acc: List[(Char, Int)]): List[(Char, Int)] = charList match {
    case Nil => acc
    case x :: xs => rec(xs.filter(_ != x), (x, charList.count(_ == x)) :: acc)
  }
  rec(chars, List())
}
```

This method was used in week 4 assignment :)

Comment: Thanks. I also had thought of this method. Just wanted to use an advanced version after going through week 5 tutorials. Thats a way to implement new concepts right? :-D